# Not Getting The Response From In-App Billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am Implementing Android In-App Billing in my app But I am not getting Json Response from Google play.

```
    @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                 if (Consts.DEBUG) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "buying: " + mItemName + " sku: " + mSku);
                    }
                 mSku="android.test.purchased";
                    if (mManagedType != Managed.SUBSCRIPTION &&
                            !mBillingService.requestPurchase(mSku, Consts.ITEM_TYPE_INAPP, mPayloadContents)) {
                        showDialog(DIALOG_BILLING_NOT_SUPPORTED_ID);
                    } else if (!mBillingService.requestPurchase(mSku, Consts.ITEM_TYPE_SUBSCRIPTION, mPayloadContents)) {
                        // Note: mManagedType == Managed.SUBSCRIPTION
                        showDialog(DIALOG_SUBSCRIPTIONS_NOT_SUPPORTED_ID);
                    }

            }
        });
```

I m getting Screen where Google play Ask For card no. like  "VISA XXX-FAKE" and Accept & Buy Button. After clicking on accept & buy i am not getting response.

I think something went wrong here while click on "OK" button to buy. I haven't changed anything in Sample code. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that when using the "VISA XXX-FAKE" method you can only get signed responses if you pre-register your device ID under your developer account.