# Android In-App billing not getting a response

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I've downloaded the example app ("Dungeons") and replaced the item-id in the requestPurchase method witch the debug id "android.test.purchased". Everything works fine, I get directed to the playstore where I can execute a fake purchase (VISA xxx-FAKE), and after returning I even get a Toast that tells me my article will be available shortly.
But neither the onRequestPurchaseResponse nor the onPurchaseStateChange method gets called. I have a Galaxy S2. On my friends Galaxy S it works perfectly.
Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

I've found this similar question: [Not Getting The Response From In-App Billing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033363/not-getting-the-response-from-in-app-billing)
but I believe the answer is incorrect, because I don't find anything in my developer console to register my device-ID.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now I tried adding 'android:debuggable="false"' to my manifest and that worked.

Apperently posting questions on stackoverflow helps me solve my problems on my own, even if I was failing for days before :-D